# Circular import during run multiprocessing

Tags: django, multiprocessing

I have example like this:

File models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

File db_request.py

```
from .models import Document

def get_all_documents():
    return Document.objects.all()
```

File services.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from .db_request import get_all_documents

def stream():
    docs = get_all_documents()

def start_streams_documents():
    pr = Process(target=stream)
    pr.start()
    pr.join()
```

File admin.py

```
from .models import Document
from .services import start_streams_documents

@admin.register(Document)
class MachineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','text')

    change_list_template = 'admin/document_table_changelist.html'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [path('start_streams/', self.start_streams)]
        return my_urls + urls

    def start_streams(self, request):
        start_streams_documents()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

If i call in `services.py` stream, i get an error `Apps aren't loaded yet.`. Ok, let's add `import django django.setup()` to `db_request.py` at first. Then i'll get an error `circular import`. The example is as simple as possible, what am I doing wrong? If i call `stream` without multiprocessing, it will work

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 120, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 130, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\Desktop\Screener V3\app\documents\services.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .db_request import get_all_documents
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\Desktop\Screener V3\app\documents\db_request.py", line 2, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fr3st\Desktop\Screener V3\app\documents\admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .services import start_streams_documents
ImportError: cannot import name 'start_streams_documents' from partially initialized module 'documents.services' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\fr3st\Desktop\Screener V3\app\documents\services.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, a solution from another site helped me.

> There is a good workaround Python circular import error that you can
> import the module itself rather than importing object/function from
> the module. This way you can import and use all the objects and
> variables from the module.

In `admin.py` i need replace this:

```
from .services import start_streams_documents
```

to:

```
import documents.services as service
....
service.start_streams_documents()
```